# Using if logic with match

Tags: r

I want to create a new column containing an number indexed from another column. The choice of column depends on the indexed number.

I've tried using if loops, but can't work out how to achieve this

```
testdata <- data.frame(sample=c("A01", "A02", "A03"),
                       mode=c(187, 189, 190),
                       control=c("A03",NA,NA),
                       mancontrol=c(NA, 191, 192))


expectedresults <- data.frame(sample=c("A01", "A02", "A03"),
                              mode=c(187, 189, 190),
                              control=c("A01",NA,NA),
                              mancontrol=c(NA, 191, 192),
                              ctrlmode=c(190, 191, 192))
```

I need to create a new column at the end, 'ctrlmode'.

A) If there is a value for that row in the 'mancontrol' column I want this value put into 'ctrlmode'.

B) If 'mancontrol' is NA, I want to look up the control sample in the 'control' column, then look up the control sample's mode in the 'mode' column, and put that mode into the new 'ctrlmode' column.

I'd be hugely grateful for some help!
Thanks!

Comment: Please show the expected output perhaps `> testdata %>% mutate(ctrlmode = coalesce(mancontrol, mode))` or `testdata %>% mutate(ctrlmode = case_when(!is.na(mancontrol) ~ mancontrol, TRUE ~ mode))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` with `case_when`.   The logic is if there are non-NA elements in 'mancontrol, return the 'mancontrol' or else `match` the 'control' with the 'sample' to get the index and use that to subset the 'mode'

```
library(dplyr)
testdata %>%
   mutate(ctrlmode = case_when(!is.na(mancontrol) ~ mancontrol, 
           TRUE ~ mode[match(control, sample)]))
```

if we have multiple types, then make sure than the output have only a single type as `case_when` does the type check

```
testdata %>%
   mutate(ctrlmode = case_when(!is.na(mancontrol) ~ as.numeric(mancontrol), 
           TRUE ~ mode[match(control, sample)]))
```

---

Or we can create an index and use that to assign

```
i1 <- is.na(testdata$mancontrol)
testdata$mancontrol[i1] <- with(testdata, mode[match(control, sample)][i1])
```

Comment: I've found a problem: if 'mancontrol' contains all 'NA', then I get the following error ```Error: Evaluation error: must be a logical vector, not a double vector
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace.``` ###example dataset: ```testdata <- data.frame(sample=c("A01", "A02", "A03"),
                       mode=c(187, 189, 190),
                       control=c("A03","A03","A03"),
                       mancontrol=c(NA, NA, NA))```

Comment: @Mike IN that caase, just wrap `as.numeric(mancontrol)` because `case_when` is specific about types.  You can't have multiple types

Comment: @Mike Can you check the ouptut now